# Does converting a list to a set change the order of elements?

Tags: python, list, set

When I do something like:

```
U = [(1.0, 0.0), (0.0, 1.0)]
set(U)
```

It gives me:

```
{(0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0)}
```

I just want to convert the list into a set. Any help?

Thanks

Comment: That is a list of tuples.

Comment: By "change the sequence", do you mean "change the order"?  Sets don't have an order, and the order they're displayed in and/or iterated over is completely arbitrary.

Comment: `set`s are inherently unordered.

Comment: Does it need to be a `set` or can you get away with just removing duplicates?

Comment: `{(0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0)}` is a set.

Answer (score 3):

Sets are not ordered.  Dictionaries are not ordered either.  If you want to preserve a specific order, then use a list.

```
>>> ''.join(set("abcdefg"))
'acbedgf'
>>> ''.join(set("gfedcba"))
'acbedgf'
>>> ''.join(set("1234567"))
'1325476'
>>> ''.join(set("7654321"))
'1325476'
```

Obviously, when you iterate over a set *some* kind of order has to come out.  But the order is an arbitrary order which you cannot specify.

Here's my favorite:

```
>>> {'apple', 'banana'}
{'banana', 'apple'}
>>> {'banana', 'apple'}
{'apple', 'banana'}
```

The order is affected by hash collisions, so it's not only dependent on the contents of the set but the order of insertion too.  But you have no real control over the order.

Comment: I think what is confusing the OP is that they think the order of elements inside the tuples have been rearranged (since the two tuples are symmetric). You may want to explain that.

Comment: @jurgenreza: You know, it would be much more efficient to just explain things to the OP rather than bugging random other people in an effort to get them to explain it.  I don't think you're right, anyway.

Comment: Jesus! I meant no offense, I thought since your answer is complete and good you may want to add a line to it. What an attitude!

Comment: @jurgenreza: No offense taken.  But it is a pet peeve of mine--somewhat often I get asked on SO to expand on an answer that is ordinarily adequate, by someone who already knows the information I had written--because they think that someone else entirely *might* not understand some crucial point.  And this person always seems knowledgeable enough to expand the answer themselves, but always asks me to do it instead.  So: no harm done, just don't make requests like that in the future.

Comment: Ok I see your point. It seems like a personal preference. I sometimes get the same type of comments and find them useful to improve my answer.

Comment: Probably because I'm a beginner, I can't fully understand your explanation. Like I don't even know what does join do. But my classmate just told me that order doesn't matter in set. So I think problem solved. Anyway, thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: @whitecatgsd: `''.join(x)` just smashes strings together, like `''.join(['abc', 'def'])` gives you `'abcdef'`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is confusing you is the symmetric nature of the tuples. Converting the list to a set has not affected the arrangement of items in the tuples but rather the order of the tuples. And that is because sets are unordered by nature. Here is another example with asymmetric tuples.

```
>>> U = [(2.0, 0.0), (0.0, 1.0)]
>>> set(U)
{(0.0, 1.0), (2.0, 0.0)}
```